# Линия рисуемая в tkinter не следует за курсором

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Линия не следует за курсором.

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry('900x600')
brs=6
def paint(event):
    x1=event.x-brs
    x2=event.x+brs
    y1=event.y-brs
    y2=event.y+brs
    canv.create_oval(x1,x2,y1,y2,outline='black')
canv=Canvas(root,bg='white',width='2000',height='2000')
canv.bind('<B1-Motion>',paint)
canv.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Метод `create_oval` в качестве аргументов принимает координаты **левого верхнего** и **правого нижнего** углов квадрата, в который вписан овал или, в данном случае, окружность. Поэтому, во-первых, координата `y1` должна быть больше координаты `y2`. Во-вторых, необходимо поменять порядок аргументов c `x1,x2,y1,y2` на `x1,y1,x2,y2`:

```
def paint(event):
    x1=event.x-brs
    x2=event.x+brs
    y1=event.y+brs
    y2=event.y-brs
    canv.create_oval(x1,y1,x2,y2,outline='black')
```